# Writing a method that accepts an object as a parameter, and uses its methods to do something (java)

Tags: java

I have a list provided by my teacher and he wants me to know every concept. I know them all pretty well, except for the last one on this list:

-Be comfortable with variables, declaring and initializing, and basic data types like int, double, String and Boolean

-Know conditional logic. Be able to write if statements

-Be able to write some basic for or while loops

-Be able to write a simple method, that takes some parameters, and returns something

-Know enough about objects to be able to declare, instantiate them, and use their methods to do things

-Be able to write a method that accepts an object as a parameter, and uses its methods to do something

I worked on a little project to test out how well I knew these things, and I did this without any references, even google: https://gist.github.com/KamronKelley/3272e2c7c63741b2f47f87d6819b944e 
(this is the code that's at the bottom also, but this is easier to view imo)

I'm not sure I used the last requirement (the one in bold) in this project, but if I did please let me know (and where).

If I didn't use it (which I'm pretty sure is the case), how could I implement it in this project?

I haven't tried much because I just don't know how to do the step in bold at all in Java.

```
package banking;

public class Accounts {
    String name;
    double balance;

    public Accounts() {
        name = "";
        balance = 0.0;
    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void addFunds(double addedAmount) {
        balance = balance + addedAmount;
    }

    public void withdraw(double withdrawnAmount) {
        balance = balance - withdrawnAmount;        
    }

}




package banking;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BankSimulator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Accounts a1 = new Accounts();

            Scanner scAccountName = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Hello and welcome to the banking system. Please enter a name to create an account, no spaces: ");
            a1.setName(scAccountName.next());
            System.out.println("Account name: " + a1.getName());

        int count = 0;
        while(count == 0) {

            int toDo;
            Scanner scToDo = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("What would you like to do next?"  + "\n" +
                "Change account name: press 1"  + "\n" +
                "See account name: press 2"  + "\n" +
                "Check balance: press 3"  + "\n" + 
                "Add money to balance: press 4"  + "\n" +
                "Withdraw money from balance: press 5" + "\n" +
                "Exit program: press 6: "); 

                toDo = scToDo.nextInt();

            if(toDo == 1) {

                Scanner scNewAccountName = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.println("Enter new account name: ");
                    a1.setName(scNewAccountName.next());
                    System.out.println("Account name: " + a1.getName());
            }
            else if(toDo == 2) {
                System.out.println("Account name: " + a1.getName());
            }
            else if(toDo == 3) {
                System.out.println("Current balance: $" + a1.getBalance());
            }
            else if(toDo == 4) {
                Scanner scAddMoney = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Desired amount to add: $");
                a1.addFunds(scAddMoney.nextDouble());
                System.out.println("Money successfully added to balance."); 
            }
            else if(toDo == 5) {
                Scanner scWithdrawMoney = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Desired amount to withdraw: $");
                a1.withdraw(scWithdrawMoney.nextDouble());
                System.out.println("Money successfully withdrawn from balance.");
            }
            else if(toDo == 6) {
                System.out.println("Thank you for using our banking system. Until next time.");
                count = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your exact problem?  Do you not understand how to call a method on an object?  (Hint: you are already doing it!)  Do you not understand how to pass an object as a parameter?  (Hint you are already doing it!)   Can't you think of an example to implement?  Hint: consider "transfer x dollars from `this` account to another one.

Comment: I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in Stack Overflow so you can narrow down your question.

Answer (score 1):

If your issue is truly not understanding the below bullet:

> -Be able to write a method that accepts an object as a parameter, and uses its methods to do something

You are already doing it! Let's break down how...

> "Write a method that accepts an object as a parameter"

That means we need to write a method that takes in an object -- some instantiation of a class -- in its method. So maybe one way to reword it could be: "***We need an action that requires an object (which is subsequently able to perform actions) in order to perform it's action***"

So you have created a new account, `a1`, using the line: `Accounts a1 = new Accounts();`.

> In the line: `a1.setName(scAccountName.next());`, you are using a
>   method (`setName`), that is being passed the result of an object
>   (`scAccountName`)'s method (`.next()`)

So if we break that down:

- Method: `.setName()`
- Object passed: `scAccountName`
- Object's method: `.next()`

Congratulations =)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clearly understand your question. But if you are going to ***write a method that accepts an object as a parameter, and uses its methods to do something***, you can try like this.

```
public interface Human {
    void say();
}

public void test(Human human) {
    ...
    human.say();
    ...
}
.....
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    object.test(new Human{
        @Override
        public void say() {
            System.out.println("saying...")
        }
    })    

}
```

Or simply pass a lambda as the parameter.

```
object.test(() -> System.out.println("saying"))
```